# LSTM model is not created with Keras

Tags: python, keras

I try to make a function to build a LSTM model with Keras, but google.colab returns me this error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_5" (type Sequential).
Input 0 of layer "lstm_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (8,)
Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=int32)
  • training=None
  • mask=None
```

My code:

```
def build_LSTM(len, activation, optimizer):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(num_words, len, input_length=max_len))
    model.add(LSTM(boxes))
    model.add(LSTM(32))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation=activation))
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer, 
        loss='binary_crossentropy', 
        metrics=['accuracy'],
    )
    return model

LSTM = build_LSTM(8, "sigmoid", "rmsprop")
LSTM.fit(my_data...)
```

I tried to add `return_sequences=True`, but it isn't work

Answer (score 0):

The issue is as per `https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/`, where it states the following:

"inputs: A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature]"

So your inputs to the LSTM layer do not have the right shape.